# DIV collapses background image

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a section container that holds a div (.tablet). Both section and Div are responsive

When the view port reaches > 400px, I want to display a background image in my div (.tablet)

HOWEVER, unless I specify a px width and height, the div collapses and disappears. It ignores the background image. It's Almost as if the background image does not exist and the div has no content!

Is it possible to create a resposnive DIV with a flexible background image that does not collapse? I want the background image to fill the DIV and respond with the div size?

i've tried using the following rules with the .tabletonly div

```
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed; /* Fixbackground * */
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
HTML 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>

<head>
     <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style1.css"/> 

</head> 
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="section">




 <div id="tabletonly" class="span_1_of_2">
    <div><div>
    </div> 


</div> // end wrapper
</body>  
</html>
```

CSS code ----------------------------------------

```
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%; 
}



@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {

#tabletonly div{
    background: url("images/shop.jpg" );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

}

Comment: nb. a background image is just that, a background- and not content. As such, it is subject to the dimensions of the element to which it is applied. You will either need to apply dimensions to `.tablet` or, instead of using a background image, toggle the display of an `img` element

Comment: If you're not putting anything in the div, just use an IMG tag, and swap those out.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the aspect ratio of the background image, there's a trick you can use to keep the box from collapsing - use border-box box-sizing, set the height to 0, and give the div a padding-bottom that reflects that ratio.

```css
.image-box {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/600x300/eee/ccc');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%; /* match this to the aspect ratio of your picture */
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmakesthings/61bxcdm6/%20jsfiddle)

That being said, the other commenter had a point; depending on your use context, maybe this should be an inline image rather than a background one?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that. If I do understand your question, it will Center the background image and it will keep the ration as well.

```
background-size:contain;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image: url(../images/YourBackgroundImage.png);
```

Using contain will skink or enlage your image, but will be fully visible. Make sure your background image is good enough for big screen,

The position will center from Top and from Bottom. 
Make sure the image does not repeat as that make look bad.
And of course the Image you want to put as background.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `tabletonly` div has height of 0 because it has no displayable content in it.
Perhaps you may specify `min-height` (i.e. may use vh, % or px) or populate div with content.
It is difficult to tell as I do not know what you need the div for.